# Service installed on Windows 7 machine is not reading from its config file

Tags: windows-services, app-config

I have a .Net 3.5 web service that installs perfectly on my old XP box.  I recently got a beautiful new Windows 7 box and everything has been working wonderfully.  Yesterday I remembered that I need to instal this service on my new box and attempted to perform the install.

After the install I did a quick test and it seemed to be working correctly.  Later in the day, I went into the config file and made a small change.  After restarting the service I was dismayed to discover that the change was NOT being picked up by the service and it continued to use the old values.

Can someone explain how this is possible?  I am totally befuddled here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've most likely been a "victim" of [Windows Backward Compatibility (aka UAC Data Redirection)](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx).

When a program running as non-admin tries to write to config files located in Program Files, Windows redirects the write to another (user local) directory. That means, a user can seemingly write the file, but another user will see the original, Program Files, version.

Comment: I opened UltraEdit as Administrator and all of a sudden I was seeing to original values.  I changed the value and saved and it's working properly now.  Thank you so much!